# How can I exclude certain chars from using regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex which looks like `(?![A-Z])[0-9]+\.?[0-9]?+`

This currently finds

The last portion of
I00001.12

and

00000.12
00000

But I don't want it to find I00001.12 or any part of that string

is this possible with Regex?

Comment: so you don't want it to match numbers that have a letter to their left?

Comment: Wait, there's probably a simpler solution to that - are you simply trying to valid that a string is numeric in nature? Please give us some example inputs and outputs.  Also - let us know what language you're using, not all Regex is created equal.

Comment: You know what checking for numeric might just work! my situation is  as much as I hate it I have to use some kind of check to ensure an ident is numeric (when its numeric) its an image - if it has I its a different type of item and a D is another type of item - yuk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to match pure floating point numbers. If so, try using following regex

```
^[0-9.]+$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pK5dN4)

---

**Note :** Above regex is very crude. If you have strict requirement of matching only valid floating points, consider using following regex.

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

-- based on comments from *@FrankieTheKneeMan* and *@anubhava*

Comment: That is a lot simpler - but it still matches the I0005.1

Comment: @Rob did you use `^` and `$` ? Please check posted demo

Comment: I would've `^\d+(\.\d+)?` for floating point, to eliminate malformed things like `"192.168.0.1"`.  And it defenitely won't, @Rob, unless that's a one at the beginning of that string instead of an L or an i.  [See](http://regexr.com?375jo)

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan true. but it all depends on OP's requirement and data. works fine for posted samples. I wouldn't like to complicate the regex unless absolutely required.

Comment: interesting it works in the demo but not in notepad++ - ok I will do some testing in my App and get back to you

Comment: Thats because in notepad++ your data is probably different to what you have provided us. This regex works exclusively if the number is alone on its own line.

Comment: @Rob It works for me even in `Notepad++`. Probably you have some spaces?

Comment: Ok so I tried it in the the application and that regex works - your right about notepad++ - because in the app its only checking the exact ident not the whole line - great solution - thank you

Comment: @anubhava agree. as mentioned in previous comment, it's simple if requirement is not strict. Also added strict regex.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following Regex...

```
\.\d*
```

Good Luck!